# Is there an easy way to compute mean and standard deviation from Pandas value_counts Series?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

For testing whether a statistical difference occurs between to (large) samples I want to compute the mean and sd from a value_counts Series:

In [0]: counts.value_counts()

```
0    783 
1   1128  
2    744  
3    366  
4    119   
5     38   
6     10    
7      3
```

I'm aware calculating the mean is not hard at all by doing something like

```
total = 0
for idx, val in counts.value_counts().iteritems():
    total = total + idx*val
m = total/sum(sum(counts.value_counts()))
```

I'm asking if there's a shorter way of doing this.

And I'm also asking how to calculate the the standard deviation from the counts.value_counts() output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pandas series index to get mean of the indexes

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4], columns = ['num'])

np.mean(df['num'].value_counts().index)
#op
2.5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do these.

```
counts.value_counts().mean()
counts.value_counts().median()
counts.value_counts().mode()
counts.value_counts().std()
```

Comment: This gives me the mean (and std) of the actual values. I would like to have the mean of the indexes(?). So from my example the mean would be 1.397994.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the mean from value counts by doing a weighted average with `numpy.average`:

```
counts = df.value_counts()
np.average(counts.index, weights=counts)
1.3979943591350674
```

Stdev is a little more tricky since it is less common to do that analysis with weights, but it looks like there is something in `statsmodels` that can help:

```
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import DescrStatsW

weighted_stats = DescrStatsW(counts.index, weights=counts, ddof=0)
weighted_stats.mean, weighted_stats.std
(1.3979943591350674, 1.1904965747995073)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about describe(). It can be used on a series or dataframe.

[DataFrame.describe(percentiles=None, include=None, exclude=None, datetime_is_numeric=False)](http://DataFrame.describe(percentiles=None,%20include=None,%20exclude=None,%20datetime_is_numeric=False))

```
df.describe() # returns dataframe containing describes for each column.
df['counts'].describe() # describe for values
df['counts'].value_counts().describe() # describe for value_counts()
df.value_counts().describe()['mean'] # returns mean
df['counts'].describe()[['mean','std']] # returns mean and std
```